# py/pandas dataframe - how to change daily closing prices into monthly closing prices?

Tags: python, pandas

My pandas dataframe looks like this:

```
            VTI       VOO       VGK      IEV
2017-06-20  125.5809  224.3456  55.2675  44.43
2017-06-21  125.1100  223.5591  54.8000  44.05
2017-06-22  124.7800  223.1609  54.8200  44.06
2017-06-23  124.8100  223.1200  54.8400  44.10
```

i run

```
m_price = price.resample('BM', how=lambda x: x[-1])
```

which works but tells me: "FutureWarning: how in .resample() is deprecated
the new syntax is .resample(...)..apply()"

can someone please help me with the new syntax? Thanks
(Py 3.6.1 / Pandas 0.20.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataFrame.resample()` returns `Resampler` object. Then you can use one of the methods on it: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#resampling

In this case you need [`last()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.last.html#pandas.core.resample.Resampler.last):

```
m_price = price.resample('BM').last()
```

Answer (score 1):

v0.18.0 (March 13, 2016) documentation says,

> API breaking change to the .resample method to make it more .groupby like, [see here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0180-breaking-resample).

You can use [these](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#resampling) functions on your resampler objects.

And the my answer is,

```
m_price = price.resample('BM').last()
print(m_price)

               VTI     VOO    VGK   IEV
2017-06-30  124.81  223.12  54.84  44.1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to summarize your data across a down-sampled frequency, you can use [**`pd.DataFrame.asfreq`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html)

```
df.asfreq('BM')
```